# check if value is a url or not in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project that some of its pictures don't come from the media folder so I wanted to know if there's a way for me to check if the value is a link to use media.poster instead of media.poster.url ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if image is in your media folder or not by this:

```
default_storage.exists(".../site_media/media/image.png")
```

It will return false if image is not in your media folder, then it must be some url.
If i misunderstood your question, kindly correct me so I can provide a solution accordingly.